# Unable to add multiple docs to Couchdb because of identical _ids

Tags: python, couchdb

I use `couchdb` module to deal with CouchDb in Python. One strange thing happens when I try to insert many different docs. When I print this docs before they are inserted to the database I see a lot of identical automatically generated `_id` fields. My own dictionaries even do not have such a key (I mean `_id`), but still couchdb generetes them automatically and make a lot of clones. I do insertion like this:

```
print(mydict) # here I see a lot of identical keys for different elements
db.save(mydict)
```

Comment: What do you execactly use to access CouchDB from python? Which strategy do you use for ID generation? Because CouchDB will only create a unique-id, if you do not provide on on INSERT and i don't think couchdb fails at generating unique-ids.

Comment: I used no strategy to generate IDs. As I said "My own dictionaries even do not have such a key" and "couchdb generetes them automatically". And, ,yes, it fails to generate unique-ids. I tried another approach after that - using of uuid.uuid1 function. And that function also generated in a loop identical `ids`. So, I gues, the same thing happens here.

Comment: If you see a `_id` before executing `save()`, you are updating a existing document. Either you create a new `mydict`, or remove the `_id` if you want to create a _new_ document in couchdb. https://github.com/djc/couchdb-python/blob/master/couchdb/client.py#L406-L407

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems as if documents are inserted too fast, then you may get a lot of identical `_id`s. Instead of default `_id` value, I now get hard-coded _ids with python `ObjectId()` function:

```
mydict['_id'] = str(ObjectId())
```

That enables me to insert multiple docs "at once"

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be mistakenly using `db.save`, because you will not insert two documents when calling it multiple times with the same object.
If your data has a `_id` value, a UPDATE of the document will be done, else a INSERT.
These should be no problem with CouchDB generating duplicate IDs, it might be you using the same id over and over againt.
In case you want to generate the Ids on the client side, have a look at this part of the documentation: https://github.com/djc/couchdb-python/blob/master/couchdb/client.py#L389-395